# Adding colon or dash after section

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec

I changed the format of `subsubsection` to remove the line breaks after them using `titlesec` package and the command

`\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{3pt}{}`

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{3pt}{}
\begin{document}

\section{Section one}
Some text
\subsection{Subsection one one}
Some text
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one one one}
This is subsubsection. Blah blah blah.

\end{document}
```

This produces the subsubsection title immediately followed by the body.
Now, I want to add a colon (or dash) after the title. e.g.

> **1.1.1. Subsubsection one one one**: This is subsubsection. Blah blah blah.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Added the working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the optional argument of `titleformat` meant for after code:

```
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{3pt}{}[:]   %%<--- this one
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{3pt}{}[:]
\begin{document}

\section{Section one}
Some text
\subsection{Subsection one one}
Some text
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one one one}
This is subsubsection. Blah blah blah.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The other answer only works for *some* of the predefined shapes (for example, `runin` as in the question), but will fail in some cases (`display`, or `block`, see example at the bottom).

The proper way to do these kind of additions (see the `titlesec` documentation, Section **4.4. Putting a Dot after the Section Title**, page 12) is to define a command with a mandatory argument to be used in the last argument for `\titleformat`. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand\colonafter[1]{#1:}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{3pt}{\colonafter}

\begin{document}

\section{Section one}
Some text
\subsection{Subsection one one}
Some text
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one one one}
This is subsubsection. Blah blah blah.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As I already mentioned, the other answer's approach works in the OP's situation because the `runin` format was used, but the solution proposed there will fail for other shapes as this example shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{3pt}{}[:]

\begin{document}

\section{Section one}
Some text
\subsection{Subsection one one}
Some text
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one one one}
This is subsubsection. Blah blah blah.

\end{document}
```

Resulting in the wrong output:

[image]